# Installing Ubuntu ruined my Windows

Tags: system-installation

I've been using Windows 10 and wanted to install Ubuntu (dual boot) through Universal USB Installer.

Once it has completed, I restarted my PC. Then comes GRUB page which I can choose try ubuntu or install ubuntu and so on.

The problems are: I can't access the ubuntu and also I can't access my previous Windows OS, it still loads that GRUB page and whenever I click on any choices, it just goes blank page and automatically restarts.

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Remove the installation USB.

Comment: If you see an option to install, you are not looking at the grub menu.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, you actually are if you are booting from the install disc in EFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

boot from the usb and click try ubuntu them 
try this

---

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

---

it will try to fix the grub if not (work) try to unsitall and reinstall ubuntu 
o se

Answer (score 0):

As Pilot6 implied, with boot menu options you've posted, it sure sounds like you've left the USB stick in. If not, try the Boot Repair procedure posted by edymola. Boot Repair has saved my butt more than once.